# jQuery Animate after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="oglasi_list_big">
    <li>
        <a href="test.html">
            <img src="/gallery/dummy_img_300x250.jpg" alt="test" />
            <div class="info_box">
                <table>
                    <tr><td class="title">TEST</td><td class="tag_deluxe">TEST</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2">TEST</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="title">TEST</td><td class="title">1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>150м2</td><td>2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" class="title">TEST</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2">TEST</td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><br/><span class="btn_more">TEST</span></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <span class="price_tag price_deluxe">2&euro;</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following javascript:

```
$(".oglasi_list_big li a").on("mouseenter", function(){
         $(".info_box", this).animate({top:'0'}, 500);
         $(".info_box > table", this).animate({marginTop:'0'}, 500);
     });

     $(".oglasi_list_big li a").on("mouseleave", function(){
         $(".info_box", this).animate({top:'200px'}, 500);
         $(".info_box > table", this).animate({marginTop:'-10px'}, 500);
     });
```

The jQuery animate is giving animation to the image, it's moving up and down... It's working fine if the content is not loaded with AJAX, but if the HTML is loaded after the page load with AJAX, the animation doesn't work. I thought that .on() will solve the problem, but it's not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should always do `$(document).ready(function(){})` for jQuery. Also please provide a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net) to make it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's in $(document).ready, but the issue is not that, since it's working if the content is not loaded with AJAX. .animate is not recognizing the elements after they are created with AJAX.

Comment: If you added the ajax code (and how you handle the result) helping you would be a lot easier